# Google API Crux API - Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "collectionPeriod": Cannot find field.'

Tags: google-api, google-search-api

I'm trying to set a date range using collectionPeriod for the google Crux API (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/api/)

```
url = "https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryRecord?key=key"


headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"}

data = {"origin":"https://www.example1.com",
        "metrics": ["largest_contentful_paint", "experimental_time_to_first_byte"],
       "collectionPeriod": {
      "firstDate": {
        "year": 2022,
        "month": 10,
        "day": 12},
      "lastDate": {
        "year": 2022,
        "month": 11,
        "day": 1}}
       }


response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

However when I try the above I see the error:

> {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid JSON payload received.
> Unknown name "collectionPeriod": Cannot find field.', 'status':
> 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type':
> 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations':
> [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
> "collectionPeriod": Cannot find field.'}]}]}}

Comment: The documentation isn't very good. Could it be that `collectionPeriod` is only part of the [response body](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/api/#response-body) see "for example" rather than the [request body](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/api/#request-body)?

Comment: @DazWilkin - I think you're right, they seem to have mixed it up, its in the response body not the request, ty!!